# Python manual query building: how to escape strings for MySQL in list comprehension where clause builder?

Tags: python, sql, django, escaping, list-comprehension

I'm using Django for a site, but I can't use Django's ORM because it's not built for "n" databases dynamically selected by user with joins between multiple databases, otherwise trust me I would love to.

I'm stuck building the query by hand and take a look at this trickery with list comprehension:

```
  def buildQuery(self, pagedata, num_per_page) :

    given_fields = {k:v for k,v in self.entity.FIELDS.items() if k in pagedata.iterkeys()}    
    where_clauses = [(given_fields[k] % pagedata) for k in given_fields if pagedata[k].strip() != '']

    if where_clauses: 
      self.queryparts['whereclause'] = 'WHERE ' + ' AND '.join(where_clauses)
    else:
      self.queryparts['whereclause'] = ''

    if pagedata.get('sort_by', '1') != '':
      self.queryparts['sortby'] = 'ORDER BY %s %s' % (pagedata.get('sort_by','1'), pagedata.get('sort_dir','asc')) 
    else: 
      self.queryparts['sortby'] = ''

    self.queryparts ['limit'] = 'LIMIT ' + self.buildLimit(pagedata.get('page',1), num_per_page)
    return self.entity.QUERY % self.queryparts
```

What the above does is take the intersection of GET fields from the page and the class fields. A sample "entity" looks like this:

```
  class event:
    FIELDS = {'keyword': "(rmt.title LIKE '%(keyword)s' OR rmt.episode_name LIKE '%(keyword)s') ", 
              'service_name': "(s.short_name LIKE '%(service_name)s' OR rch.aliases LIKE '%(service_name)s')", 
              'puid': "ime.program_unique_id LIKE '%(puid)s%%'",
              'ims_theme': "",
              'content_type': "rmt.types IN ('%(content_type)s')",
              'genre': "rmt.genres LIKE ('%(genre)s')", 
              'service_uid': "s.service_uid IN (%(service_uid)s)"}

    QUERY = '''SELECT rme.image_path image, rmt.title title, ime.program_unique_id PUID, s.short_name service_name, s.service_id sid, ime.begin_time, ime.ims_event_id FROM %(imsdb)s.service s JOIN %(imsdb)s.event ime ON ime.service_uid = s.service_uid LEFT JOIN %(rmsdb)s.event rme ON ime.eit_id = rme.event_id AND rme.service_uid = ime.service_uid LEFT JOIN %(rmsdb)s.text_data rmt ON rmt.text_id = rme.text_id LEFT JOIN %(rmsdb)s.channellogo rch ON rch.suid = s.service_uid %(whereclause)s %(sortby)s %(limit)s'''
```

The only **problem** is I have is with this line:

```
where_clauses = [(given_fields[k] % pagedata) for k in given_fields if pagedata[k].strip() != '']
```

How do I escape apostrophes in a field?

The databases will always be MySQL for the foreseeable future.

For more completeness on how this is "used", here's what my Django view looks like:

```
def index(request):
  cursor = connection.cursor()
  q = QueryBuilder(entity=QueryBuilder.event, rmsdb=sources.getCurrentRMSDB(request), imsdb=sources.getCurrentIMSDB(request))
  SQL = q.buildQuery(request.GET, num_per_page)
  return HttpResponse(SQL)
  cursor.execute(SQL)
  return render(request, 'rma/event.html', {'results' : dictfetchall(cursor)})
```

Comment: This is a work in progress and nothing is caught yet (i.e. if a database doesn't exist or a table in that db doesn't exist) i'll crash nicely later.

Comment: It is generally advised NOT to pass parameters into queries through string functions (SQL injection for one thing), but pass them through the driver and let the driver do the escaping/casting/etc.

Comment: well i'm building my query in this class, you're suggesting I pass in the cursor as well and use execute('''SQ''', (data)) ? I don't think execute understand named-string-format to replace things by name.

Comment: DB API cursors do understand mapped parameters afaik. Why not let your builder class return a tuple containing the parametrized query and the parameters.

Comment: This is a private intranet network and on copy of data. Users blowing away the DB has no consequences since the next time data is copied (twice a day) everything is refreshed (schema, data, indexes etc). So Injection is not my top priority.  .... I think cursor.execute() will still have problems with apostrophes since it's invalid SQL.

Comment: Ok I just tried returning only "query_parts" dict from buildQuery() above and changed execute to do: 

  query_parts = q.buildQuery(request.GET, num_per_page)
  cursor.execute(QueryBuilder.event.QUERY, query_parts)

... but still I get a INVALID SQL statement. Looks like execute doesn't replace apostrophes like I thought. ?keyword=test's still fails. :(

Comment: Try to narrow down your error. E.g. Try `cursor.execute('select %s;', ("abc'def",))`. If this works (works for me with psql via python DB API), the driver does correctly escape apostrophes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is widely known enough and solution is specified in [PEP249](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/): connector module's `paramstyle` defines how to pass strings without need for manual escape. In usual MySQL driver, `paramstyle` = `"qmark"`, but it also understands `pyformat` style.

Also you can format these string constants manually, but, due to SQL specifics, this is very DBMS dependable.

Comment: Can you kindly show me how I'd use it in my code? I don't know where to put what code. my execute is in my view. How would I change this line: return self.entity.QUERY % self.queryparts

Comment: You should use `cx.execute(query_text, *args)` where "cx" is cursor object. So, using '%' to make final query text is improper - query text and parameters shall be passed to driver separately and only driver knows how to assemble the final query. It's possible it will send them separately to server, and the latter will assemble the query without need to reparse.

Comment: I tried that too. still get invalid SQL due to apostrophe in one of the strings. It doesn't seem to escape it.

Comment: @dlite922 could you please show an isolated publicly allowed example?

Comment: I'd have to modify my code a bit to do that. Since execute() replaces my table names with quotes around them as well, I need to the IMS DB name replacement manually (with %) then pass the rest to execute(), however with % some names can't be missing I believe. I'll try it and see what I can come up with.

Comment: so I'm running into issues with this design. I can't have named string formats for DB names (table prefixes) if I can't give the whereclause sort_by and limit keys also. I can't give db names to execute() because it puts a quote around it, which is invalid syntax. (e.g. ... FROM 'db1'.event JOIN ...)... So Now I'm stuck. 

I need a solution to escape strings \'. Probably just run a repalce ' with \' for every GET data field value.

Comment: @dlite922 I guess you first should to read SQL standard and its specific issues in different DBs. For instance, quoting database names with *single* quotes are incorrect anywhere. In SQL standard, there shall be double quotes here (opposed to data values, which shall have single quotes!) But for MySQL this is effective only if ansi_quotes is defined in SQL connection mode, otherwise *backticks* shall be used for database/table/column names, but both single or double quotes for values.

Comment: @dlite922 Second, string escaping is also specific in each SQL dialect. But standard mode is to double a quoting character to put it literally into string. Backslash as prefix is MySQL extension. Postgres style has differences in quoting, and so on. That's why using driver's knowledge to quote string values is better in most cases.
Third, if you use manual quoting ' to \', you should also quote backslash itself! (your description doesn't expose whether you have done this).

Comment: Yes my solution only works for MySQL. good catch on the slash.